# angulary way to have a condition for if data.property == true, then display the property, else do nothing

Tags: angularjs, controller, conditional-statements

I have data that I'm displaying in the view like this which works fine:

```
  <p class="ytTitle">{{ channel.ytTitle }}</p>
```

from a dataset like this:

```
[{
  "id": 150,
  "ytId": "UC7YGvsMTJ7KroZRaUTiF5PQ",
  "property": true
}]
```

And I want to know the best way to say something like {{ channel.property ? "property" : "none" }}.  replace "property" with something that looks up the name of that property.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this `channel[variableName]?channel[variableName]:"none"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of AngularJS are you using? AngularJS 1.2 supports the ternary operator, so you can do:

```
{{ channel.property ? 'property' : 'none' }}

{{ channel.property ? channel.property : 'none' }}
```

Older versions require a workaround, like these:

```
{{ channel.property && 'property' || 'none' }}

{{ channel.property || 'none' }}
```

Comment: 1.1.5 supports as well I guess.